# How to enable Duplicate Tab feature in Studio 3T

Tags: mongodb, studio3t

In Studio 3T Ultimate for MongoDB (2022.3.0), I follow a process similar to Robo 3T where I double click a collection which opens a tab with results for that collection. I then make changes to the query and load the results. In Robo 3T I could right-click the tab and choose "Duplicate Query in New Tab." However, in Studio 3T when I right-click the results tab, there is an option called "Duplicate Tab" but it is greyed out. How do I un-grey or enable the "Duplicate Tab" feature so that I can reuse the query in a new tab?